# JSON Callback not being called

Tags: jquery, json, callback

The following code has worked in v1.3 but not 1.4 I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. I'm building a cities ddl from a selection from the province ddl. I'm using ASP.NET MVC 2

The function on the server gets called and it builds up the correct list, but when it returns it never steps into the callback function. I've put in some alerts, and the don't get called.  except for the one before the getJSON

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

$(function () {

```
 var provinces = $("#ProvinceId");
 var cities = $("#CityId");

 provinces.change(function () {
     cities.find('option').remove();
     alert("hello outside JSON call");

     $.getJSON('<%= Url.Content("~/HomeController/Cities") %>', { province: provinces.val(), includeAllPlaceholder : true }, function (data) {
         alert("hello");
         $(data).each(function () {
             alert("hello 2");
             $("<option value=" + this.Value + ">" + this.Text + "</option>").appendTo(cities);
             alert(this.Value + ":" + this.Text);
         });
     });
 });
```

});

in the controller

```
public JsonResult Cities(string province, bool includeAllPlaceholder)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            int provinceId;

            if (int.TryParse(province, out provinceId))
            {
                var values = ReferenceTableService.CitiesInProvince(provinceId).Where(f => includeAllPlaceholder || (includeAllPlaceholder == false && f.IsAllPlaceholderEntry == false)).ToList();
                values.Sort();

                items.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "", Text = Resources.Global.Generic.ddlSelectValue });
                items.AddRange(values.Select(f => new SelectListItem { Value = f.Id.ToString(), Text = f.Name }));
            }

            return Json(items);
        }
```

thanks

TR

Comment: Tried running the JSON through JSON lint (http://jsonlint.com/) to be sure it's valid?

Comment: What does console.log(data) || alert(data) output? Are you sure that you're getting correct data back?

Comment: @Idriz Sunja the alert(data) doesn't get executed. I put it right above alert("hello")

Comment: @LaceySnr I checked it on JSON lint but I'm not exactly sure what to do with the error message 
Parse error on line 1:
$(document).ready(fu
^
Expecting '{', '['

Comment: `$(document).ready(fu ^` shouldn't be there, when something expects JSON it expects pure JSON, so it should be starting with `{`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for all the help folks. turns out I needed to add in `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` to my return statement

```
return Json(items); => return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

*sigh

Answer (score 1):

From [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

> Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of JSON data for this reason. JSON is a data-interchange format with syntax rules that are stricter than those of JavaScript's object literal notation. For example, all strings represented in JSON, whether they are properties or values, must be enclosed in double-quotes. For details on the JSON format, see http://json.org/.